# Different output in production and development mode(GWT)

Tags: java, gwt, awt

I am working on draw a shape in GWT canvas. Everything is working fine. Only the problem is when I rendered shape in development mode then image draw correctly but when I ran same program in production then its draw same with some extra line.

I am not getting any idea why same program output behaves different in different mode.

For extra information I also used awt in gwt program.

[image]

Any idea why this work differently in different mode?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using the same versions of browsers when you test it in both your Development & Production environments, if not these problems are expected with GWT. I had faced similar issues on Production too, where my Development and Staging environments were hosting IE 10 whereas on Production environment, there were users who use IE 8 and 9.

To fix the issue I've written client specific (browser specific, browser version specific) CSS and JavaScripts... Hope this gives you a direction towards solving your problem!

Comment: I believe this not CSS or JS related issue. I used same browser for both development and production environment.